# Google API Data YouTube v3 (error: invalid_grant - Bad Request)

Tags: php, google-api, youtube-api

[Скачать архив проекта](http://te0.ru/2015_12_13.zip)

Код без авторизации, задаем только ApiKey приложения, [работает нормально](http://te0.ru/index_1.php)

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/php/Gapi/vendor/autoload.php';
set_include_path( __DIR__ . '/php/Gapi/src');
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setDeveloperKey('AIzaSyAjqunVy9S_Jm8HMncSS0WZkkqBNBsebck');
$youtube = new Google_Service_YouTube($client);
try{
    $listSearch = $youtube->search->listSearch('id,snippet',array(
        'q' => 'Dogs',
        'maxResults' => 30,
    ));
    $html = '';
    foreach($listSearch['items'] as $searchItem){
        switch($searchItem['id']['kind']){
            case 'youtube#video':
                $html .= '<a target="_blank" href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v='.$searchItem['id']['videoId'].'">'.$searchItem['snippet']['title'].'</a><br>';
            break;
        }
    }
    echo $html;
}
catch(Google_Service_Exception $e){
    echo $e->getMessage().'    '.$e->getCode();
}
catch(Google_Exception $e){
    echo $e->getMessage().'    '.$e->getCode();
}
```

Код с авторизации через Service account keys, [не работает](http://te0.ru/index_2.php)

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/php/Gapi/vendor/autoload.php';
set_include_path( __DIR__ . '/php/Gapi/src');
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAuthConfig( __DIR__ . '/pn-gapi-201d1056019b.json');
$client->setScopes(array(
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.upload',
));
$client->setApplicationName('an_gapi');
$client->setAccessType("offline");

$youtube = new Google_Service_YouTube($client);
try{
    $listSearch = $youtube->search->listSearch('id,snippet',array(
        'q' => 'Dogs',
        'maxResults' => 30,
    ));
    $html = '';
    foreach($listSearch['items'] as $searchItem){
        switch($searchItem['id']['kind']){
            case 'youtube#video':
                $html .= '<a target="_blank" href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v='.$searchItem['id']['videoId'].'">'.$searchItem['snippet']['title'].'</a><br>';
            break;
        }
    }
    echo $html;
}
catch(Google_Service_Exception $e){
    echo $e->getMessage().'    '.$e->getCode();
}
catch(Google_Exception $e){
    echo $e->getMessage().'    '.$e->getCode();
}
```

**Несколько дней поисков ошибки результатов не дали:**
[image: Создание проекта в google console]
[image: Включил API YouTube]
[image: Список всех включеных API]
[image: Заполнил контент скрин для OAuth на всякий случай]
[image: Добавил ключь разработчика]
[image: Добавил service acaunt и получил json файл с данными аутентификации]
[image: Список ключей]
[image: Изменил политику безопасности для учетной записи google]
[image: Проверил серверное время]

[Скачать архив проекта](http://te0.ru/2015_12_13.zip)

Comment: Какая ошибка-то возникает?

Comment: { "error": "invalid_grant", "error_description": "Bad Request" } 400

Comment: Смотрели гид по [OAuth 2.0 for Server to Server Applications](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/auth/service-accounts)? – там иначе, чем у вас реализовано.

Comment: Да, я видел этот пример, но по-моему он мне не совсем подходит, в этом примере они авторизуются как администратор облака чтоб иметь доступ ко всем данным пользователей внутри облака, я же хочу управлять своим каналом ютуб, и дать возможность пользователям моего сайта заливать видео на мой канал

Comment: Взаимодействие происходит между серверами, ваши пользователи туда не имеют доступа – поэтому можно и полный доступ дать. Но прочитайте по ссылке раздел «[Delegating domain-wide authority to the service account](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/auth/service-accounts#delegatingauthority)», п. 6, который вы, очевидно, пропустили.

Answer (score 1):

В оф. документации «[Using OAuth 2.0 for Server to Server Applications](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/auth/service-accounts)» приведены примеры на PHP – как раз то, что вам нужно.

Как задать права приложения – описано в разделе [Delegating domain-wide authority to the service account](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/auth/service-accounts#delegatingauthority) – там в п.п.6 вы зададите только доступ к youtube, youtube.upload.

Comment: $user_to_impersonate = 'user@example.org';
$credentials = new Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials(
    $client_email,
    $scopes,
    $private_key,
    'notasecret',                                 // Default P12 password
    'http://oauth.net/grant_type/jwt/1.0/bearer', // Default grant type
    $user_to_impersonate,
); но такого класса нет, зато есть другой Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials но при его вызове не происходит автозагрузки, попытался раскоментировать его в autoload_classmap.php но результат тот-же, может покажите как его подключить

Comment: К стати вопрос где взять полный репазиторий клиента , тот что есть у меня был собран по запчастям https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client тут только часть клиента без папки **vendor**. Тут нашел папку **auth** https://github.com/google/google-auth-library-php

Comment: > без папки vendor

Так там надо [composer](https://getcomposer.org/) запустить же ж.